# How to format the print of a data frame in R using sprintf?

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

Suppose I have a data frame with columns of mixed modes (text and numeric):

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c(5.21, 6.32, 18.14), C = c(14.7, 9.1, 7.22))
```

and I would like to eventually format the output to look like (e.g.,) the following using sprintf and adding the currency signs and percent characters:

```
  A     B     C
1 a  $5.21  14.7%
2 b  $6.32   9.1%
3 c $18.14   7.2%
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scales` package has `dollar()` and `percent()` functions that can do this:

```
df$B <- dollar(df$B)
df$C <- percent(df$C / 100)
```

Comment: This is great but since it converts all objects to type character its not clear how one sets the number of digits to display (since 'format' also converts numeric to character).

Comment: percent seems to have a built-in digit selection and it works for my application - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need `ifelse`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c(5.21, 6.32, 18.14), C = c(14.7, 9.1, 7.22))
forme<-function(x,y){
  xy<-ifelse(x=="currency",'$%s','%s%%')
  sprintf(xy,y)
}
df$B<-forme(x="currency",df$B)
df$C<-forme(x="percent",df$C)
```